# Shopify add extra parameter with buy button

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I am new to [shopify](https://www.shopify.in/) , I have created a product with buy button JS SDK and generated embed code.
Now, I want to send extra parameters with checkout button which can be displayed at backend.

can anyone help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, line item properties are not yet supported by the [JS Buy SDK](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk). They are, however, on our roadmap and we hope to have a solution to this available soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `cart.attributes` property of Shopify cart.

More details - https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes#create-a-cart-attribute-field

Comment: thanks but I am not using themes and etc I have just integrated buy button apis.

Comment: In that case you can use AJAX - https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api